# VLOOKUP in a FILTER-ed range while automatically adding new rows

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, formulas

I have an easy-to-append monthly purchase log:

```
month prod  count
-----------------
jan   water 10
jan   bread 20

feb   bread 2
feb   water 1
```

And I want to get a friendlier summary table:

```
 prod  jan feb
 -------------
 water 10  1
 bread 20  2
```

Any idea how I can get this raport with new months in log appearing automatically as new columns?

I managed to get the month heads  with a `=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(log!A2:A, log!A2:A<>""))))` and I am ok with entering the prod column by hand but I only managed to have a formula per column for count. And that means I need to drag the formula with each new month added to the log...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

`=QUERY(A:C,"select B, sum(C) where A <> '' group by B pivot A")`

[image]

See more info here:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Use number of months instead of names to get `1, 2, 3` from `feb, jan` ordered alphabetically

Comment: I tried that too, but I need to specify the exact order of product columns... This is why I used VLOOKUP in the first place. It's not alphabetic. Can I specify that with Query pivot?

Comment: This is possible in two ways: 1. Make ugly huge formula, 2. Make script. This is not essicient because the task is very specific. I still suggest using numbers instead of month names.

Comment: How about if I would add a (auto-calculated) helper column with a sorting key?